# How to serve static file using restify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, restify

Ok, I have seen lots of similar questions but none of those have solved my problem or are pair to the actual version.
I'm trying to use `Restify` after a long time with `Express`.

```
import restify from "restify";

const server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("%s listening at %s", server.name, server.url);
});

server.get(
  "/",
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: "./public",
    default: "index.html"
  })
);
```

I was expecting that my `index.html` file would be displayed as I access the `/` route. But my server is looking for the css in `/css/style.css` 
instead of looking at `public/css/style.css`.

Any hint on how to solve this? Also any material on how to undestand this better would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try using `server.get(/\/?.*/, restify.plugins.serveStatic({...}));` instead.

Comment: Didn't work :/. Thanks for the try tho